# php5-fpm failing to start after upgrade of Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, php, ubuntu-12.10

I upgraded my laptop on the weekend from Kubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 and all seemed fine, until I started working again.

The laptop is a webdev machine running Nginx and php via php5-fpm but now it seems that php5-fpm will not start. When I run /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart I just get a message that says FAIL. I am not getting any messages in syslog or /var/log/fpm-php.www.log to give hints on what's happening. I am running ps to check that there is indeed no PHP processes running. I have also tried changing the listen parameter from 127.0.0.1 to listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

Can anyone suggest some things to try in order to solve this issue?

php version 5.4.8; php5-fpm version 5.4.8

Comment: this may be related http://serverfault.com/questions/177322/php5-fpm-fails-to-start .. port might be already in use

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, I checked that the port was free and tried it on other ports to be more sure.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say I solved the problem but I have fixed it. I replaced my whole /etc/php5 directory with that of my Debian 6 production server and all is working now. A *diff* shows many differences throughout the files but nothing is obvious. If I get a chance I'll work through each differences to see the key problem.